# Algorithm conjecture

Tags: analysis, algorithms

This is an algorithm analysis question for computer science.

Let f(n) be positive functions. (Dis)prove the following conjecture?

$$f(n)+o(f(n))\in\Theta(f(n))$$

o above is the Little O, defined as this:

$g(n) \in o(f(n))$ when $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{g(n) \over f(n)} = 0$

Comment: Hint: if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{g(n) \over f(n)} = 0$, then there is a $N\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $g(n)/f(n) < 1$ (or equivalently $g(n)<f(n)$ ) for all $n>N$.